# Polar to cartesian form of r=sin(3θ)

Tags: trigonometry

$$\sin(2θ) = \sinθ\cosθ + \cosθ\sinθ = 2\sinθ\cosθ $$
$$\cos(2θ) = \cosθ\cosθ - \sinθ\sinθ = \cos²θ - \sin²θ $$

$$\sin(3θ) = \sin(2θ+θ) $$
$$= \sin(2θ)\cosθ + \cos(2θ)\sinθ $$
$$= 2\sinθ\cos²θ + \cos²θ\sinθ - \sin³θ 
$$ $$= 2\sinθ(1-\sin²θ) + (1-\sin²θ)\sinθ - \sin³θ 
$$ $$= 2\sinθ - 2\sin³θ + \sinθ - \sin³θ - \sin³θ 
$$ $$r=\sin(3θ)= 3\sinθ - 4\sin³θ$$
How to deal with the differing exponents? I could add an $r$ to both sides or $r^3$ but not both. 
 $$r^4= 3r^3\sinθ - 4r^3\sin^{3}θ   $$
 $$r^4= 3r^2y - 4y^3$$
 $$(x^2+y^2)^{4/2}= 3(x^2+y^2)^{2/2}y - 4y^3$$
 $$(x^2+y^2)^{2}= 3(x^2+y^2)y - 4y^3$$
 $$(x^2+y^2)^{2}= 3yx^2-y^3$$

Comment: In the future, please use \sin and \cos and \theta.  They will look much clearer if you do so.  Also, you can use ^2 to do exponents.

Answer (score 2):

Go with $r^3$.  If you have an extra $r^2$ lying around, you can replace it with $x^2+y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: 
$$r=3\sin(\theta)-4\sin^3(\theta)=\sin(\theta)\{ 4\cos^2(\theta)-1\}$$

Now put: $\cos(\theta)=x/r$ , $\sin(\theta)=y/r$ and $r=(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$.

This will give you: $$r=\frac{y(4x^2-r^2)}{r^3}$$ which implies $$(x^2+y^2)^2=4x^2y-y(x^2+y^2)=3x^2y-y^3$$

Comment: The implicit plot of the answer is quite odd: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E2%3D+3(x%5E2%2By%5E2)y+-+4x%5E3

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(3\theta) = 3\sin\theta - 4\sin^3\theta$$

$$\sin^3\theta = \sin\theta\cdot \sin^2\theta$$

$$r = 3\sin\theta - 4\sin\theta\sin^2\theta$$

Hence

$$r^2 = 3r\sin\theta\left(1 - \frac{4}{3}\sin^2\theta\right)$$

$$r^2 = 3y\left(1 - \frac{4}{3}\frac{r^2}{r^2}\sin^2\theta\right) = 3y\left(1 - \frac{4}{3r^2}y^2\right)$$

So

$$r^2 = 3y - \frac{4y^3}{r^2}$$

And again

$$r^4 = 3yr^2 - 4y^3 \to r^4 = 3y(x^2 + y^2) - 4y^3$$

Arranging the terms you get

$$r^4 = 3x^2y - y^3$$

Comment: @Dale I edited my answer.

Comment: @ShreyAryan I think you wrote in the wrong post.

Comment: I think the comment got deleted.

Comment: @ShreyAryan What comment? The OP commented in YOUR answer, not on mine.

Comment: @ShreyAryan saw your edit and deleted my comment before seeing your comment^^

Answer (score 1):

#### Hint

$$\sin3\theta=3\sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^3(\theta)$$